# Parallel.For out-of-sync output

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm kind of new to the parallel programing classes in C# 4.0; Was trying a simple for loop, where I should normally get longs from 0 to 99 printed in sequential fashion with the usual for loop, but with the Parallel.For, I'm getting incosistent outputs in random jumbled-up orders.

Code :

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
            {
                //object sync = new object(); 
                //lock (sync)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Writing" + i);
                }
            });
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

One output on console :

```
Writing0
Writing1
Writing2
Writing3
Writing4
Writing5
Writing6
Writing7
Writing8
Writing9
Writing10
Writing11
Writing12
Writing13
Writing14
Writing15
Writing16
Writing17
Writing18
Writing19
Writing20
Writing21
Writing22
Writing23
Writing24
Writing25
Writing26
Writing27
Writing28
Writing29
Writing30
Writing31
Writing32
Writing33
Writing34
Writing35
Writing36
Writing37
Writing38
Writing39
Writing40
Writing41
Writing42
Writing43
Writing44
Writing45
Writing46
Writing47
Writing48
Writing49
Writing50
Writing66
Writing67
Writing68
Writing70
Writing71
Writing72
Writing73
Writing74
Writing75
Writing76
Writing77
Writing78
Writing69
Writing82
Writing83
Writing84
Writing85
Writing86
Writing87
Writing88
Writing89
Writing90
Writing51
Writing52
Writing53
Writing54
Writing55
Writing91
Writing92
Writing93
Writing94
Writing95
Writing56
Writing57
Writing79
Writing80
Writing81
Writing58
Writing59
Writing96
Writing97
Writing98
Writing99
Writing60
Writing61
Writing62
Writing63
Writing64
Writing65
```

Thanks in advance, for whatever help you guys get me.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, "I know, I'll use threads," and then two they hav erpoblesms. https://twitter.com/nedbat/status/194452404794691584

Comment: Parralel foreach does not guarantee in order executuion. I gurantees that all threads will finish before proceeding. Seriously, read some documentation. There is nothing inconsistent about the output; in fact it's consistently inconsistent as with all unsynchronized threads.

Comment: daveL - you didn't read the very first line of my Question. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be? You're asking for multiple iterations to be executed in parallel, but also expect the results to be completely serialized (1, then 2, then 2, …). That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You're right. But getting them to execute in a serial/synchronized fashion (somehow) will also OFTEN be the challange.

Comment: @Ronnie No, it's not a challenge. If you really need that, just use `for`, not `Parallel.For()`. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is parallel computing. The tasks are queued up and each available processor gets one. If it is done, the next queued task will be issued to it. There is no guarantuee about the order in which the tasks will be delivered to the processing units as well as no guarantuee which one will be finished next, therefore parallizable code is not the same as sequential code + the keyword `parallel`. The algorithms need to be developed to be able to run in parallel. In your simple example all numbers from 1 to 100 are written, but the parallel loop does not write them in the natural order you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected, the way you are doing it there the work is partitioned using the current thread as well as a number of others pulled from the thread pool.

If you wanted to do the same thing on a different thread but make the writting synchronous then you could try :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
                for(var i = 0;i<100;i++)
                {
                    //object sync = new object(); 
                    //lock (sync)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Writing" + i);
                    }
                }
            });
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. So that's how you write the for loop that takes advantange of parallel computing/ TPL, but gets executed only in the order that a standard for loop would aim to ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: “there is a different thread created for each iteration” That would be very inefficient and it's certainly not what `Parallel.For` does.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more correct with how the method works. You are correct it is not a new thread for each iteration (probably). Instead it partitions the iterations across the current thread as well as several others pulled from the thread pool.